# Error while installing Swift Package - unable to access /Package.swift

Tags: swift, iqkeyboardmanager, swift-package

I recently added a Swift Package (IQKeyboardManager) from GitHub on to my xcworkspace Project. The Package.swift file is in the root folder of the repository. However, I got an error: /Package.swift cannot be accessed

[image]

Unable to resolve the error.

1. How do I fix it?
2. How do I remove Swift packages?

I tried updating the package a number of time, without luck. As I am not able to delete the package from the Project, I am not even able to run the project now.